# INotifyPropertyChanged does not work when the property set to a same value for the second time

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, inotifypropertychanged

This is the code to reproduce this issue:

xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Num,  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}"></TextBox>
</Grid>
```

C#:

```
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows;

namespace WpfApplication1
{
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.DataContext = new Entity();
    }
}

public class Entity : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private double num;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    public double Num
    {
        get { return num; }
        set
        {
            num = value;
            if (value > 100)
            {
                num = 100;
            }
            OnPropertyChanged("Num");
        }
    }
}
```

}

Now, if I run it, input 1, it's ok. Then input another 1, which makes it 11, it's still ok.
And then input another more 1, which makes 111, now the validation will work and change the value to 100, and the UI will show 100.
But then if I input more numbers, the UI will not change, it'll be 1001.

I guess it has something to do with setting the property to the same value(100) for twice.
But I have no idea how to fix it, by fix it, I mean to make the UI always follow the property value.

Thanks

Comment: You are checking whether value is > 100.  1001 is indeed greater than 100, and so it is accepting the value, but setting the private field to 100.  What did you expect to happen?

Comment: I don't think your code above accurately represents your real code; the setter above *only* sets the value if it's `> 100`, and it sets it to `100`. If it's less, it never actually sets the value.

Comment: @Chris Shain : I'd expect the UI to change to 100, since the property value is 100 even when you input 1001.

Comment: @Adam Robinson : I just updated the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
    <Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
   <Window.Resources>
        <!--The Too tip for the textbox-->
        <Style x:Key="txterror" TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="Validation.HasError" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="ToolTip"
             Value="{Binding RelativeSource={x:Static RelativeSource.Self},
              Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"></Setter>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Red"></Setter>
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
       <TextBox x:Name="txt" Text="{Binding Mode=TwoWay, IsAsync=True, Path=Num,  UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" Margin="63,36,71,184" >
            <TextBox.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect  ShadowDepth="5"/>
            </TextBox.Effect>
        </TextBox>
        <TextBox Margin="63,96,71,124" Text="{Binding ElementName=txt,Path=Text}">
            <TextBox.Effect>
                <DropShadowEffect ShadowDepth="5" />
            </TextBox.Effect>
        </TextBox>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Use above code its working fine logicaly.
means that when u set value of Num proeprty it setting proerty value to 100 but the textbox values of your widnow is not changed.
it is because of the framework element it uses the Error validation so what so ever u want to put into textbox it will type that and present that value on the textbox. but the property values is always 100 when ever its goes higher then 100.

Your Solution is to use the **IsAsync=True** in you binding statement

Comment: thank, but I already know that. now what I need to know is how to make the UI always follow the property value.

Comment: Your Solution is to use the IsAsync=True in you binding statement

Comment: Er, your solution is to make the binding async?

Comment: thanks, "IsAsync=True" helps. but now the cursor is always at the left-most side of the text box, any idea how to fix this?

Comment: I know this is old, but it helped me.  An explanation of why this works would be great.

Answer (score 0):

actually it should work as long as your input in your textbox can automatically converted to double. did you check your output window for bindingexceptions? if you debug with values like 1001 what happens in your setter?

Comment: No, no bindingexceptions. If I set a breakpoint in the setter, what happens is that the value will be set to 100.

Answer (score -1):

Introduce property changed notification before truncating `num` to 100 and one immediately after truncating...

like this...

```
        num = value; 
        OnPropertyChanged("Num");
        if (value > 100) 
        { 
            num = 100;
            OnPropertyChanged("Num"); 
        }
```

Let me if this helps.